# NSSpeechSynthesizer delegate method always reports an error, but which one?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

I have  the following delegate method for NSSpeechSynthesizer:

```
- (void) speechSynthesizer:(NSSpeechSynthesizer *)sender didFinishSpeaking:(BOOL) success {
    NSLog(@"Finished correctly = %d", success);
    [startButton setEnabled:YES];
    [stopButton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

The parameter "success" is always NO, even though I heard everything perfectly. Is there a way to get more information and find out **exactly** what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `NSSpeechSynthesizer`? No. Using the Speech Synthesis Manager? Sure thing!

```
/* Created earlier: SpeechChannel chan; */
NSDictionary *errorInfo = nil;
OSErr err = CopySpeechProperty(chan, kSpeechErrorsProperty, (CFTypeRef *)&errorInfo);
[errorInfo autorelease];
```

You can also set up error handlers for all kinds of errors. See the [Cocoa Speech Synthesis Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaSpeechSynthesisExample/Introduction/Intro.html) for a demonstration of how to use the Speech Synthesis Manager. While it is a Carbon API, it appears that it is still available to 64-bit applications.